# Prove $A=B$ if $A\times C=B\times C$ where $A, B$ and $C$ are all sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Let $A, B$ and $C$ be sets, with $C\neq\emptyset$. Suppose $A\times C = B\times C$.
>   Prove that $A = B$. (Be sure you clearly convey where the hypothesis $C\neq\emptyset$ is used.)

I already proved that $A=B$ by proving the products are subsets of each other but I don't know what $C\neq\emptyset$ is used for?

Comment: Note that $X\times\varnothing = \varnothing$ for every set $X$. Clearly  the hypothesis $C\neq\varnothing$ is necessary.

Comment: So does it still hold if C = ∅?

Comment: "So does it still hold if $C=\emptyset$" No it does not.  $\{1\}\times \emptyset = \{2\}\times \emptyset$ despite $\{1\}\neq \{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach that students take is the following:

Suppose that $A\times C=B\times C$.

$\color{red}{(\dagger)}$  $\underline{\text{Let}~ a\in A~ \text{and let}~ c\in C}$.  So then $(a,c)\in A\times C$.

As $A\times C\subseteq B\times C$ it follows that $(a,c)\in B\times C$ as well implying that $a\in B$.  This will prove that $A\subseteq B$.  The opposite containment can be proven the same way.

---

The error in this proof is at $\color{red}{(\dagger)}$.  By taking an arbitrary $a\in A$ and $c\in C$ we are tacitly assuming that such a selection is even possible in the first place which it is not guaranteed to be.  In particular we are not able to make such a selection when $A=\emptyset$ or when $C=\emptyset$.

In order to correct the proof, we must consider those cases where one or both are empty separately.  We find that when $A=\emptyset$ and when $C\neq \emptyset$ that this will imply $B=\emptyset$ as well and vice versa so that part is fine.  However, if we allow $C$ to be empty the theorem fails.  For example $\emptyset\times \emptyset=\{1\}\times \emptyset$ despite $\{1\}\neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof should assume that the products are equal (and so are subsets of each other) and show that the sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of each other.

Comment: Would you explain your wry use of English?  Note that A is not a subset of AxC if C is empty and A is not empty, if that was what you were talking about.

Comment: Please read my post carefully.  Notice that I wrote that the proof should begin by assuming the products $A \times B$ and $A \times C$ are equal and so are subsets of each other.  Proceed by showing that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: How so?  Let A = {0},  B = {1 ,2}.

Comment: William, there is no nonempty set $C$ for which your sets $A$ and $B$ satisfy the condition that $A\times B = A \times C.$